# Code won't read folders in the same directory

Tags: python, file

**Background info.**
I'm trying to implement three functions `transition_model`, `sample_pagerank` and `iterate_pagerank` in the `pagerank.py` file all the code in such file except those three functions is given by the professor. There are other three folders (`corpus0`, `corpus1`, `corpus2`), which contain HTML files for the websites to be ranked, in the same folder(named `pagerank`) where `pagerank.py` is found. I'm not supposed to change anything in the file but the three functions. Yet any suggestions like such would be appreciated.

**Error info.**
The code stops in line 13 due to sys.argv == 1 instead of 2. After some googling I now know that sys.argv[0] is the path for `pagerank.py` and sys.argv[1] should be the path for one of the folders but the code will not find any of the three folders. I also found that the `os` library is to read folders, but I don't see any use of such library in main

**Guesses.**
I tried removing two out of three folders, it didn't work. I'm new to python so I don't really know how python reads files and its syntax.

**pagerank.py**

```
import os
import random
import re
import sys
import numpy as np

DAMPING = 0.85
SAMPLES = 10000


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: python pagerank.py corpus")    <----- Stops here.
    corpus = crawl(sys.argv[1])
    ranks = sample_pagerank(corpus, DAMPING, SAMPLES)
    print(f"PageRank Results from Sampling (n = {SAMPLES})")
    for page in sorted(ranks):
        print(f"  {page}: {ranks[page]:.4f}")
    ranks = iterate_pagerank(corpus, DAMPING)
    print(f"PageRank Results from Iteration")
    for page in sorted(ranks):
        print(f"  {page}: {ranks[page]:.4f}")


def crawl(directory):
    """
    Parse a directory of HTML pages and check for links to other pages.
    Return a dictionary where each key is a page, and values are
    a list of all other pages in the corpus that are linked to by the page.
    """
    pages = dict()

    # Extract all links from HTML files
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if not filename.endswith(".html"):
            continue
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename)) as f:
            contents = f.read()
            links = re.findall(r"<a\s+(?:[^>]*?)href=\"([^\"]*)\"", contents)
            pages[filename] = set(links) - {filename}

    # Only include links to other pages in the corpus
    for filename in pages:
        pages[filename] = set(
            link for link in pages[filename]
            if link in pages
        )

    return pages


def transition_model(corpus, page, damping_factor):
    """
    Return a probability distribution over which page to visit next,
    given a current page.

    With probability `damping_factor`, choose a link at random
    linked to by `page`. With probability `1 - damping_factor`, choose
    a link at random chosen from all pages in the corpus.
    """
    distribution = dict()


    # Iterates through all corpus' keys 
    for current in corpus:
        if current == page:
            for link in current:
                distribution.update( link = damping_factor / len(current) + ((1 - damping_factor) / len(corpus)) )

            return distribution

    for link in corpus:
        distribution.update( link = damping_factor / len(corpus) + ((1 - damping_factor) / len(corpus)) )

    return distribution

    raise NotImplementedError


def sample_pagerank(corpus, damping_factor, n):
    """
    Return PageRank values for each page by sampling `n` pages
    according to transition model, starting with a page at random.

    Return a dictionary where keys are page names, and values are
    their estimated PageRank value (a value between 0 and 1). All
    PageRank values should sum to 1.
    """

    sample_list = set()

    # Creates first samlpe at random.
    sample_list.add(random.choice(list(corpus.keys())))

    for i in range(n):
        probability = transition_model(corpus, sample_list[i], damping_factor)
        sample_list = np.random.choise(transition_model(corpus, sample_list[i], damping_factor), )


    raise NotImplementedError


def iterate_pagerank(corpus, damping_factor):
    """
    Return PageRank values for each page by iteratively updating
    PageRank values until convergence.

    Return a dictionary where keys are page names, and values are
    their estimated PageRank value (a value between 0 and 1). All
    PageRank values should sum to 1.
    """
    raise NotImplementedError


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: how are you running the code? Like in command prompt/terminal

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` should either be just the name of a **sub-** directory of the current working directory when the script is run, _or_ it would need to be the full path to one that is not. I can tell from your description what the case is (which will likely depend on how you're running the code).

Comment: I do F5 and debug current active python file @MZ

Comment: there is no `sys.argv[1]` although there is sub - directories in the current directory, but when I run the code it wont hmmm read them or find them @martineau

Comment: Then you need to be passing the name or path to the directory as the `sys.argv[1]` when you run it (as indicated by the `"Usage: python pagerank.py corpus"`)

Comment: so the program will not do it already? because that means that I need to edit main and I'm not supposed to do so.

Comment: I literally just did `sys.argv.append(path of file)`. Is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

if you are running your code in PyCharm, go to Run -> Edit Configurations -> and in Parameters add the corpus. Example "corpus0".